# Powershell Script to Change the name of all files in a folder to the folder name

Tags: powershell

I have a folder system like the below:

```
Folder A
  Folder.A.S01.E01.MP4
  Folder.A.S01.E02.MP4
  Folder.A.S02.E01.TEST.THIS.MP4
  Folder.A.S02.E01.TEST.THIS.MP4
```

Is there a way to recurse through the folder and rename the files like this:

```
Folder A
  Folder A S01E01.MP4
  Folder A S01E02.MP4
  Folder A S02E01.MP4
  Folder A S02E01.MP4
```

Which I understand is just removing the . in the name of all files in the folder.

I have tried the following, but it removes the . file extension as well and "breaks" the file.

```
cd 'C:\Users\ME\Desktop\HERE'
dir -recurse | where {-Not $_.PsIscontainer -AND $_.name -match "."} | 
foreach {
$New=$_.name.Replace("."," ")
Rename-Item -path $_.Fullname -newname $New -passthru
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | ForEach {
    $Match = [Regex]::Matches($_.BaseName,".*S(\d+).*E(\d+).*")
    $Season = ([int]$Match.Groups[1].Value).ToString("00")
    $Episode = ([int]$Match.Groups[2].Value).ToString("00")
    $RootName = $_.Directory.BaseName

    $NewName = "$($RootName) S$($Season) E$($Episode)$($_.Extension)"
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName $NewName -WhatIf
}
```

I use this for some similar processing work, it will work on very weirdly named files and is a bit more robust, it grabs the root folder name and will use that instead of 'guessing' about removing periods from it.

```
C:\++\n\Folder1\aaaS01.E02.eee.mp4 -> C:\++\n\Folder1\Folder1 S01 E02.mp4
C:\++\n\Folder1\Folder1S01E03SOMETHING.mp4 -> C:\++\n\Folder1\Folder1 S01 E03.mp4
C:\++\n\Folder1\S01 and it is also E04.mp4 -> C:\++\n\Folder1\Folder1 S01 E04.mp4
C:\++\n\Folder1\S1E5.mp4 -> C:\++\n\Folder1\Folder1 S01 E05.mp4
C:\++\n\Folder1\something S01E01 something.mp4 -> C:\++\n\Folder1\Folder1 S01 E01.mp4
```

Just as an example of the kind of advanced renaming it can do, i'd really reccomend adding `-WhatIf` to the `Rename-Item` call and running it once first to make sure there are no issues, if the file contains more than one `S01` or `E01` or anything like that it will get confused and be unable to rename properly, although none of your example names will have this issue.

if you want to try rename alphabetized files, that the regex solution above will not match, try this:

```
$EpisodeCounter = 1
$SeasonCounter = 1
$EpisodesPerSeason = 3

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | ForEach {
    $Season = $SeasonCounter
    $Episode = $EpisodeCounter++
    $RootName = $_.Directory.BaseName

    if ($EpisodeCounter -gt $EpisodesPerSeason){
        $SeasonCounter++
        $EpisodeCounter = 1
    }

    $NewName = "$($RootName) S$($Season) E$($Episode)$($_.Extension)"
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName $NewName -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: Hello, can you explain the above a bit more? i am new ish to powershell and I understand I cant just plug and play this so I really want to understand it because i think it is exactly what i need.

Comment: Also, if it is just a bunch of files that do not have a S or E is there a way to make a sequential count as it goes?

Comment: @DefcaTrick This is mostly plug+play, it will grab any file with `SxEx` and rename it after its root folder, I've added `-WhatIf` to the command, so it wont make any actual changes, but will tell you what it WOULD do if you want to run it as a test. if you're renaming files without SxEx you have some issues, mostly that they won't be alphebetical, or that the script can't tell where to fall over to the next season - i'll add a snippet showing what you could try though.

Comment: @DefcaTrick no problem - just so you know, there's a lot of third-party tools that will probably do a better job than these scripts, unless you're importing into a media system that also does tagging i'd reccomend looking at some of them.

Answer (score 6):

FileInfo has properties `BaseName` and `Extension`. The former contains just the file name without path, the latter is obviously the extension. Combine the two like so,

```
$New=$_.BaseName.Replace("."," ")+$_.Extension
Rename-Item -path $_.Fullname -newname $New -passthru
```

That being said, consider using underscores instead of spaces. It's often a bit easier to work with files named like

```
Folder_A_S02_E01_TEST_THIS.MP4
```

instead of

```
Folder A S02 E01 TEST THIS.MP4
```

Comment: Hello, This works great! on a side note, is there a way to specify how many . to remove? ie: Folder.A.S01.E01.MP4 to Folder A S01E01.MP4 (remove first 2 . and just delete the 3rd?)

Comment: @DefcaTrick Not out of the box, but this can be done with a few ways. Please post new a question for discussing how to do it.